# Override index columns activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, batch-processing

So I would like to have a shortened table with batch actions.

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  batch_action :acitve do |selection|
    User.find(selection).each do |user|
      user.active! true
    end
  end
  filter :email
  index do
    column :id
    column :first_name
    column :last_name
    column :email
    column :sign_in_count
    default_actions
  end
end
```

However batch action box is greyd out. It's understanbale because nothing is selected. However when I use default index settings (no columns specification), the checkbox stays there. How can I have a default checkbox with custom columns?

Answer (score 2):

according to [this](http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/9-batch-actions.html) (**Customizing Table Columns** part) you need to add

```
index do
 selectable_column #batch actions checkboxes column
 column ...
 ...
end
```

to render checkboxes

Comment: WOW. That was easy :) :) :)

Comment: AA DSL is really pretty fun but sometimes lucks clear mans for simple things.. i have spent a little time to to find it at first time